# use youtube-dl Stream to create form-data

Tags: node.js, stream, form-data, youtube-dl

i want to create a nodejs service that download a youtube video and send it to another service as form-data.
I use [node-youtube-dl](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/node-youtube-dl) to download the video.

```
let YoutubeDl = require("youtube-dl");
let fs = require("fs");
let axios = require("axios");

function getVideo (req, res) {
  let videoName = "";
  let fw = undefined;

  let videoStream = YoutubeDl(req.query.url, ["--format=best[height<=480]"]);
  videoStream.on("info", (info) => {
    videoName = `${info.title}.mp4`;
    fw = fs.createWriteStream(videoName);
    videoStream.pipe(fw);
  });

  videoStream.on("end", () => {
    let fr = fs.createReadStream(videoName);
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", fr);

    const request = {
      "method": "¨POST",
      "url": "anOtherServiceUrl",
      "data": fd
      };
    axios(request).then(response => res.send(response.data));
  });
}
```

the code above works, but i don't need to write the file on the disk.

I was thinking to implement a Duplex or a Transform stream. But i don't know what to do with data when `_write` is called.